# SQLPLUS in Sublime Text

Tags: sql, sublimetext2, sqlplus

I have created `new build system` for sublime text .

```
{
"cmd": ["F:\\app\\admin1\\product\\12.1.0\\dbhome_1\\BIN\\sqlplus.exe", "C##NISAR@//localhost:1521/orcl", "@$file"],
"selector": "source.sql",
"encoding": "cp1252"
}
```

But when i run code to execute it not able to login rather showing message

```
Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

    -H         Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
           usage help.
    -V         Displays the SQL*Plus version.

Usage 2: sqlplus [ [<option>] [{logon | /nolog}] [<start>] ]
...
...
```

Comment: `C##NISAR@//localhost:1521/orcl` is not a valid connection string for SQL*Plus. It should be something like `nisar/password@orcl` provided that you have an entry `orcl` in your `tnsnames.ora`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure Nisar got this sorted by now but anyone coming here with this problem whats most likely happening is your are connecting successfully to sqlplus but it cant find the sql most likely because you haven't saved the file your working with with an .sql extension.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answer here and a tweak on another site, here's my build file that currently works...

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\app\\Oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\client_1\\bin\\sqlplus.exe", "-s", "myusername/mypassword@myoracledatabase", "@$file"]
    , "selector": "source.sql"
    , "encoding": "cp1252"
}
```

- Notice the `-s` parameter that is handy for removing all the verbose messaging before the query result table.
- I can call `sqlplus.exe` directly from anywhere in the DOS prompt, so I'm sure I could just have the first param as `sqlplus`, but I'm leaving the full path to show that the backslashes (in Windows) should be escaped if you need to specify an absolute path.